# Valor NULL antes de incrementar

Tags: flutter, dart

Estou passando valores de uma tela para outra, ao clicar em um botão na tela home envio os dados para o meus perfil. Porém se eu não clicar neste botão e for para a minha tela de perfil os campos referentes ao valores estão me retornando NULL. Gostaria que eles iniciasse com Zero mas não estou conseguindo.

Tela profile.dart

```
class ProfilePage extends StatefulWidget {
   final int valueScore;
   final int valueLifes;

   ProfilePage({Key key, this.valueScore, final int valueLifes;})
  : super(key: key);
 }
```

Mais abaixo no mesmo arquivo profile.dart eu chamo esses valores para serem mostrados em tela.

```
Text('${widget.valueScore}'),
Text('${widget.valueLifes}'),
```

No home.dart eu tenho a seguinte configuração

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
     int score;
     int saveLifes;

 void increment(){
   setState(() {
      score+=10;
      saveLifes+= 3;
  });
}
```

Ainda no mesmo arquivo home.dart, eu tenho os o botão que chama a função para incrementar o valor e passar os dados para a tela de perfil

```
increment();
Navigator.of(context).push(
  MaterialPageRoute (builder: (BuildContext context) =>
      ProfilePage(valueScore: score, valueLifes: saveLifes,)),
);
```

Se puderem ajudar em um outro detalhe, sempre que clico no botão ele passa os dados para a tela de perfil e chama ela sem o usuário ter clicado, gostaria que apenas passasse os dados e depois quando o usuário quisesse ir lá conferir.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para iniciar as variáveis com valor zerado faça assim:

```
class ProfilePage extends StatefulWidget {
   ProfilePage({Key key, this.valueScore=0, this.valueLifes=0}): super(key: key);

   final int valueScore;
   final int valueLifes;
 }
```

Dessa forma se o parâmetro não for informado ele virá com valor 0.

Para o seu outro problema, é o seguinte, sempre que você chamar o método `Navigator.of(context).push()` ele irá chamar a tela e exibi-la.
Para fazer o que deseja crie dois botões, em um você incrementa as variáveis e no outro você chama a tela passando essas variáveis incrementadas.

Segue exemplo:

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
     int score;
     int saveLifes;

 void increment(){
   setState(() {
      score+=10;
      saveLifes+= 3;
  });


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          RaisedButton(
            child: Text("Incrementar"),
            onPressed: (){
                increment();
            }
          ),
          RaisedButton(
            child: Text("Ir pro perfil"),
            onPressed: (){
              Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute (builder: (BuildContext context) => 
                ProfilePage(valueScore: score, valueLifes: saveLifes)));
            }
          )
        ]
      )
  }
}
```

**Explicação**

No seu caso, você vai estar incrementando as variáveis na Home Page e lá eles ficaram, ai no momento que abrir a Perfil Page é que você vai mandar os dados para ela, e não a todo momento que incrementar os valores na Home Page.
Não teria sentido modificar os dados na Perfil Page sendo que ela não esta sendo visualizada.